# Maximum safe temperature for Celeron 2.53GHz

Tags: cpu, temperature

I couldn't find the answer in similar topics.
please tell me.
My CPU temp is 62°C (As shown in BIOS setup) at idle and reaches 72°C when I play a 3D game for some time.
is this temp safe? what is the max temp that this CPU can work at continuously without any severe fatigue?

**From Deleted Answer**

It's a desktop PC.
I replaced my old heat sink with a new one recently that is much quieter (the reason for the change was loud noise that previous fan was producing), but the average temperature rose by 10°C.
introduced Celeron D datasheet helped me to gain necessary information and understand some facts about CPU temperature specs and cooling. I will buy a more powerful cooling system soon; I can't risk reduced life time of my CPU.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional information. This is not a forum. Please review the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) on how to use the site correctly.

Comment: You applied fresh thermal compound when you mounted the new fan, right?

Answer (score 1):

The [Celeron D datasheet](http://www.intel.com/design/celeron/datashts/304092.htm) gives the maximum case temperature at about 68°C.